# How to set up shader materials with main node Principal BSDF

Tags: export, shaders, gltf

I have issue with exporting shaders on blender model. I need to export model with shaders in GLTF . The problem is that shader materials are not exporting - only the main color of Principal BSDF node. I've got an idea from google answers, that shader materials can be exported in GLTF only if the main node will be Pricipal BSDF, that is going directly though material output node. But now i have shader mixer, that goes though material output. Is there any way to change order and plug all shaders to Principal BSDF, that will be plugged directly in material output?

[image: Pic attached]

Comment: For those of us who don't understand the language, what is the other shader you are using before the mix shader node?

Comment: @susu that is Emission node. Johny, Principled has Emission input socket itself. So try to plug emission map right into that one, move emission+mix shaders out of the way leaving only principled > output and export. That could do it if GLTF indeed works as you mentioned

Comment: @MrZak there is Color ramp node as well, and it is plugged into mix shader, how can i make it also plugged into Principal?

Comment: ColorRamp is the only one you'd be plugging since it has the emission map, mix shader is irrelevant to this. I meant to plug the output of the ColorRamp (the end of the chain with emission color map) into Emission socket of Principled, then try to export. If GLTF supports that it should be exported

Answer (score 2):

The glTF format has a different material model from Blender, and does not support arbitrary nodes.  It uses a principled PBR model powered by textures and uniforms.

For some materials, it's possible to use the Blender Cycles "Bake" panel to render a complex node graph to a texture atlas.  This allows such a material to be used even on lighter-weight mobile rendering clients that wouldn't normally support arbitrarily large numbers of shading nodes.

For complete usage instructions, see the [Blender Manual on glTF](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/import_export/scene_gltf2.html).