# Why I can't export a model with double-sided materials in gltf format?

Tags: texturing, export, shaders, gltf

When I export that by in Gltf format and open it, just the front side appears on both sides. Can you help me please?

---

In Blender

[image]

In 3D Viewer

[image]

Comment: Like most formats, glTF does not support arbitrary Blender material nodes.  See https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/import_export/scene_gltf2.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set up shader materials with main node Principal BSDF](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/209346/how-to-set-up-shader-materials-with-main-node-principal-bsdf)